# Arduino SSD1306 Display - Strange Behaviour

Tags: arduino, hardware, atmega

I have 2 SSD1306 (126x64) displays that are behaving in a very strange way:

[image: 2 failing SSD1306 and 1 working SSD1306]

Here is a short video of the sketch I ran: https://streamable.com/dl0p8j
And the sketch itself is [here](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_SSD1306/blob/3736824148ec5721b5ef5ec287d3301af3a57fb4/examples/ssd1306_128x64_i2c/ssd1306_128x64_i2c.ino) (adafruit SSD1306 + GFX). All of the displays are on I2C port 0x3c.

The one on the left is from a different producer and works fine. I can't figure out if I have defective units or if they need slightly different treatment. When the displays are written to, it seems like the entire image is drawn into the 6-8 pixel area at the top.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone has experience in this. I'm also not sure if this is the right place to post this, so let me know if there is a more fitting SE site.

Comment: What are the 3 I2C addresses that you used for the 3 displays? the link of the sketch only works for one LCD display, so what is your actual sketch for 3 displays?

Comment: They are all on 0x3C in parallel above (it is the same sketch). They behave the same individually.

Answer (score 0):

In order for I2C devices running on the same bus to work, each device need to have its own I2C addr, unfortunately the SSD1306 only has two I2C addresses that you could select, 0x3c or 0x3d.

For more than two SSD1306 running on the same I2C, you will need to either have an Arduino boards that could provided more than one I2C interface or to add some hardware solution like an [I2C multiplexer](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-tca9548a-1-to-8-i2c-multiplexer-breakout/overview).

In the meantime, if you want to run two displays together, you need to modify the code to create two display instances with different addresses.

Change the line:

```
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, OLED_RESET);
```

to:

```
Adafruit_SSD1306 display1(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, OLED_RESET);
Adafruit_SSD1306 display2(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, OLED_RESET);
```

Change the line:

```
if(!display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C)) {
  Serial.println(F("SSD1306 allocation failed"));
  for(;;); // Don't proceed, loop forever
}
```

to

```
if(!display1.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C)) {
  Serial.println(F("display 1 failed"));
  for(;;); 
}

if(!display2.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3D)) {
  Serial.println(F("display 2 failed"));
  for(;;); 
}
```

For all the subsequent calling of `display` methods, you need to change it to `display1` and add another similar line for `display2`, for example:

```
display.display();
```

will need to change to:

```
dispaly1.display();
display2.display();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip; but they still act this way individually. The working one still works, and the failing ones still fail.

Comment: Have you scanned these screens with an I2C scanner to be sure of there adresses?

Comment: Yes, they are all on 0x3C